# How do I install CUDA GPU for Visual Studio 2022 for windows 10?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, gpu, cuda

I cannot find the visual studio 2019 version and every time I try to install CUDA 11.2.2 on my laptop, It warns me about not that I haven't installed Visual Studio. I've tried installing the C++ add-ons (Mobile and Desktop development for C++) but it still warns me about the same thing. Please suggest me a way!

P.S I'm trying to install CUDA for tensorflow.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of CUDA by the time of writing the initial answer (cuda_11.5.0_496.13_win10) didn't provide support for the then relatively new Visual Studio 2022.

Support for Visual Studio 2022 came with CUDA 11.6.

You can always download an older version of Visual Studio (such as 2019) from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ and that one should work fine with older versions of CUDA.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly the need. 2022 does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Latest CUDA 11.6 added support for 64 bit compilers in 64 bit UI VS 2022. Also, you could have used nvcc even before with -allow-unsupported-compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest Windows 11, Cuda 11.8 and Visual Studio 2022 and its works to compile to models using GPU. The full explanation how to install it can be found here as solution

https://www.yodiw.com/install-tensorflow-cudavisual-studio-2022-in-windows-11-for-gpu-modelling/